# How to save value of a variable before it changes its value

Tags: python, django

I'm setting up a new website about a local crypto market, and want to control the color of the current 'ask' price by the change in price.

I used requests to get the dataset from an API provided by the market.  Than in django I passed that data to the template via a new dictionary.

views.py file;

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

def index(request):
   url = 'https://koineks.com/ticker'
   r = requests.get(url).json()
   koineks_index = {
    'fiyatBTC' : r['BTC']['ask'],
    'fiyatETH' : r['ETH']['ask'],
    'fiyatXRP' : r['XRP']['ask'],
    'fiyatBCH' : r['BCH']['ask'],
    'fiyatUSDT' : r['USDT']['ask'],
   }
   context = {'koineks_index' : koineks_index}
   return render(request, 'calc/calc.html', context)
```

html file;

```
<html>
<body>
        <p>
        BTC buy price: <span style="color:green">{{koineks_index.fiyatBTC}}</span> (₺)
        ETH.buy: <span style="color:green">{{koineks_index.fiyatETH}}</span> (₺)
        XRP.buy: <span style="color:green">{{koineks_index.fiyatXRP}}</span> (₺)
        USDT.buy: <span style="color:green">{{koineks_index.fiyatUSDT}}</span> (₺)
        BCH.buy: <span style="color:green">{{koineks_index.fiyatBCH}}</span> (₺)
        </p>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I save the price before it's updated to use in a If/else statement that will change the text-color of the current price.

I want it to be green if the updated price is higher and red if the updated price is lower than old price.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you think the database is for ?

Comment: @EminAliİpekdokuyan Sessions can solve your problem https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: @chamoda Thank you I will look into them.

Comment: @EminAliİpekdokuyan yes, that's what I suggest indeed, cf my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do:

1. store the prices in the database, with a timestamp (that will be used to know which records are the latest one, and also to find out "old" price)
2. move the API request to a custom management command - that will also be responsible for writing the results to the database - and set up a cron job to execute this command every X periods of time (depending on how fast prices change and how accurate you want to be. This will avoid hitting the API on each and every request - most API have rates limits and will kick you if you send too many requests in a given time, and a db query will usually be much faster than an HTTP request.
3. in your view, serve the prices from the database. wrt/ detecting changes, you can either compare directly with the database's stored previous batch (the one with an older timestamp) or store the current batch timestamp in the session and compare against those values, depending on what makes the most sense for you (or you can mix both: use the first solution if there's no timestamp in the session, the second if there's one).

FWIW, persisting the prices locally also allows you to display prices evolutions over a period of time... which might be more informative than a single red/green flag.

Comment: If you have another question, then post it as a new question - with all the necessary informations of course ("I couldn't figure it out" or "it doesn't work" aren't useful informations FWIW).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sessions solution

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

def index(request):
   url = 'https://koineks.com/ticker'
   r = requests.get(url).json()

   previous_prices = request.session.get('previous_prices', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

   koineks_index = {
    'fiyatBTC' : r['BTC']['ask'],
    'fiyatETH' : r['ETH']['ask'],
    'fiyatXRP' : r['XRP']['ask'],
    'fiyatBCH' : r['BCH']['ask'],
    'fiyatUSDT' : r['USDT']['ask'],
   }

   colors = ['green' if x else 'red' for x in map(lambda price: float(koineks_index[price[0]]) >= float(price[1]), zip(koineks_index, previous_prices))]

   request.session['previous_prices'] = [koineks_index[key] for key in koineks_index]

   context = {'koineks_index' : koineks_index, 'colors': colors}

   return render(request, 'price/calc.html', context)
```

Template

```
<html>
<body>
        <p>
        BTC buy price: <span style="color:{{colors.0}}">{{koineks_index.fiyatBTC}}</span> (₺)
        ETH.buy: <span style="color:{{colors.1}}">{{koineks_index.fiyatETH}}</span> (₺)
        XRP.buy: <span style="color:{{colors.2}}">{{koineks_index.fiyatXRP}}</span> (₺)
        USDT.buy: <span style="color:{{colors.3}}">{{koineks_index.fiyatUSDT}}</span> (₺)
        BCH.buy: <span style="color:{{colors.4}}">{{koineks_index.fiyatBCH}}</span> (₺)
        </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not store the colors directly with the prices instead of maintaining a distinct list ? Also, you should pass a flag (the `x` value), not a colour - how the information is rendered exactly belongs to the presentation layer (the template), not to the business domain.